# Is there an editor for Octave with a "Run" button?

Tags: matlab, octave

In Matlab, there is a built-in code editor with a "Run" button (with shortcut key F5) to run scripts. I'm looking for similar functionality in Octave; so far, I've only been able to run scripts by switching from the code editor (I use gedit) to the command line window and entering the name of the script.

Does such a code editor exist for Octave?

Answer (score 3):

The newest version of octave has a full GUI similar to MATLAB. Assuming octave is already installed you can move onto the newest stable octave version by running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you open octave now it should look like this:[image: GNU Octave GUI]

Comment: Indeed even in the version Octave 3.8 I was using, there is an experimental GUI that one can access by typing "octave --force-gui" in the command line.